# How to solve this equation with symmetric polynomials?

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

[Here is what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbQdZ.jpg)

$$x + \sqrt {17 - x^2} + x\times\sqrt{17 - x^2} = 9$$
I can`t undestand how to solve it, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Please add where are you stuck and what you know so we can help you with the problem and for the question doesn't get closed.

Comment: Formatting note:  if you want the square root to encompass a long expression, enclose the expression in curly brackets.  Thus \sqrt {17-x^2} renders as $\sqrt {17-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips!

Comment: Note:  in this case there are small integer solutions, so perhaps you were meant to solve this numerically from the start (or at least to apply the rational root theorem to the quartic polynomial one gets by squaring).

Comment: I need a symmetric polynomials way, my teacher demands, but doesn`t explain how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for adding your attempt. For future questions, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Click on "Edit" to see what lulu did to make your equation render properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using your substitution ($y=\sqrt{17-x^2}$),  we get

$$ \begin{cases} {x+y+xy=9} \\ {x^2+y^2=17} \end{cases}  $$

From the first equation we have,

$$(x+y)^2=(9-xy)^2\;\Rightarrow\ 17+2xy=(xy)^2-18(xy)+81$$
And by solving the quadratic equation in $xy$ we have $xy\in\{16,4\}$. Hence there are two cases,
$$ \begin{cases} {xy=16} \\ {x+y=-7} \end{cases}  \qquad \text{or} \qquad \begin{cases} {xy=4} \\ {x+y=5} \end{cases}  $$

Can you finish it now?

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much! Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!